# I am trying to deploy laravel 5 app on a shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have extracted my zip file(project files) to **public_html** and moved files from **public/** folder created by Laravel to **public_html** and modified index.php to

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But i am getting a 500 Internal server error? Cant it be caused by .htacces?

Comment: Because the public folder with `index.php` should be the webroot. So rename `public` to `public_html` and keep the path the same (so the other folders are still on the same lavel as public_html

Comment: can you print the stacktrace?

Comment: I am on a share hosting, I am not sure if i cant get 'stack trace'

Comment: @ThomasMoors -  so if i rename public which is inside public_html to public_html, I am going to end up with public_html/public_html?

Comment: no make public, public_html, so replace it!

Answer (score 2):

you shoud copy entire project to `public_html` and then point your domain to `public_html/your_project_folder/public/` folder

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but i dont have a option in 'Addon' to change Document root..FYI, Its on a shared hosting, I cant SSH

Comment: ok are you sure you have your .htaccess file in public folder and .env in your project folder? storage, and bootstrap folder have to be writable

Comment: i have .htaccess in 'public_html', storage and bootstrap have 775 rights and are in the same folder level as well...so 'public_html/public/' has nothing

Comment: .htaccess shoud be in public folder, where is .env file?

Comment: and you should not move file from inside public folder, leave it there

Comment: OK.... .env and .htaccess are all int the public_html folder not in public/, So i should leave everything in public, But remember i cant point to public_html/public

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158164/discussion-between-doriencragen-and-africa-matjie).